# Did Emily herself remove the memories she couldn’t remember in World of Tomorrow?

Tags: plot-explanation, world-of-tomorrow

In the short [World of Tomorrow](https://vimeo.com/153153221), when Emily took some memories from Emily Prime, was that the reason she couldn’t remember those very same memories?

Comment: This short is absolutely hilarious and at the same time deeply sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory Emily3.0 harvested from Emily Prime ("*This is me and mummy walking*") seems to be permanently gone from Emily Prime's memory. The Director explicitly stated in [an interview](http://www.cutprintfilm.com/features/interview-don-hertzfeldt-director-of-world-of-tomorrow/) that the memory was **removed**, not simply viewed or somehow duplicated

> "*I probably created the spectrum effect at the end of **her
>   memory-removal process** simply because I had a nice take of her saying,
>   “a rainbow!”*

---

Emily3.0's younger incarnation would no doubt yearn for such an important memory and would pass this yearning down to her clones each time her memories are uploaded into a new body. When the third generation Emily meets Emily Prime (through the magic of time travel), she then harvests the important memory, thereby creating a [closed temporal loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_loop).

Notably, Emily3.0 makes reference to this closed loop when she states that...

> "*she [Emily Prime] will feel a deep longing for something [she] can't
>   quite remember*"

... and that although she remembers giving a statement to her earlier incarnation, that ...

> "*[She] cannot be certain where it actually originated from*".